# Adding new item to pymongo cursor

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to add a new field to a json string (or to be more exact a bson string) so i can pass this onto the front end.

I have done a load of research, i have tried treating results like a dictionary, i tried adding the field to the database but still nothing.

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    i=10
    make = db.cars.distinct("Make")
    model = db.cars.distinct("Short Model")
    year = db.cars.distinct("Year introduced")
    results = db.cars.find().limit(i)

    print(results[0]['Make'])
    x=0
    while x < i:
        print(x)
        r = requests.get('https://izrite.com:5555/image/' + results[x]['Vehicle ID'])
        r=r.json()
        print(results[x])
        results[x]['carImage'] = r['url']
        print(results[x])
        x=x+1
    print("finished")
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', numresults=str(i), make=make, model=model, year=year, results=results)
```

existing string

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5c2bebbe7b94a040bce5eadf'), 'Vehicle ID': '74908', 'Make': 'MERCEDES-BENZ', 'Short Model': 'A CLASS', 'Long Model': 'A CLASS HATCHBACK', 'Trim': 'SE', 'Derivative': 'A160 SE 5dr Auto', 'Year introduced': '2016', 'Year discontinued': '', 'Currently Available': 'Y'}
```

desired string

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5c2bebbe7b94a040bce5eadf'), 'Vehicle ID': '74908', 'Make': 'MERCEDES-BENZ', 'Short Model': 'A CLASS', 'Long Model': 'A CLASS HATCHBACK', 'Trim': 'SE', 'Derivative': 'A160 SE 5dr Auto', 'Year introduced': '2016', 'Year discontinued': '', 'Currently Available': 'Y', 'carImage': 'http://images.capnetwork.co.uk/VehicleImage.aspx?SUBID=152231&HASHCODE=FE9015D10FEB72AE9042DB62DAC0ACFE&DB=car&CAPID=74908&VIEWPOINT=3'}
```

i would like within the json string to have a new field called carImage with the url in it, but i cant get this to work.

Comment: Where exactly are you looking at this string? Is it the `print(results[x])`?

Comment: yes both print(results[x]) are showing the same string.

Comment: What happens if you just print `r['url']` without trying to add it to `results`? What happens if you omit the first `print(results[x])`? What happens if you add some arbitrary fixed value (like the string `'HELLO'`) to `results`, instead of `r['url']`?

Comment: http://images.capnetwork.co.uk/VehicleImage.aspx?SUBID=152231&HASHCODE=B7EBF7865EE88EF0B536B694D50E17E8&DB=car&CAPID=74916&VIEWPOINT=3

Comment: and with fixed values its the same

Comment: What happens if you `print(type(results))`? And `print(type(results[x]))`?

Comment: <class 'pymongo.cursor.Cursor'>

Comment: the second print is = <class 'dict'>

Comment: I suspect that a cursor object is not meant to be updated. Are there any error messages (in a log file or something like that)?

Comment: not sure where the log file is, theres nothing on the console window. But how do i work around this?

Answer (score 0):

- I think the reason why your changes are not reflecting, is because
  you are trying to access the documents inside the cursor using an
  index (like a list), but that doesn't seem to work.
- In your last statement, you are trying to return the cursor object directly in the `render_template` function which is wrong. The cursor object is not a list (python list) of json documents as you are assuming.

The below code will work if you want to just see the changes being reflected.

```
        @app.route('/')
        @app.route('/index')
        def index():
            i=10
            make = db.cars.distinct("Make")
            model = db.cars.distinct("Short Model")
            year = db.cars.distinct("Year introduced")
            results = db.cars.find().limit(i)

            #print(results[0]['Make'])

            for doc in results:
                r = requests.get('https://izrite.com:5555/image/' + results[x]['Vehicle ID'])
                r=r.json()
                print(doc)
                doc['carImage'] = r['url']
                print(doc)
            print("finished")
#            return render_template('index.html', title='Home', numresults=str(i), make=make, model=model, year=year, results=results)
```

If you want to update all documents and return, then convert result of `find()` to a list as below. But, do note that, it will load all documents into the memory.

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    i=10
    make = db.cars.distinct("Make")
    model = db.cars.distinct("Short Model")
    year = db.cars.distinct("Year introduced")
    results = list(db.cars.find().limit(i)) #Note that here we convert the result to a list

    #print(results[0]['Make'])

    for doc in results:
        r = requests.get('https://izrite.com:5555/image/' + results[x]['Vehicle ID'])
        r=r.json()
        print(doc)
        doc['carImage'] = r['url']
        print(doc)
    print("finished")
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', numresults=str(i), make=make, model=model, year=year, results=results)
```